# Set text to DialogFragment from another class

Tags: android

I need to implement ProgressDialogFragment which extends DialogFragment. Before showing I should set the text to the dialog fragment. Here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb_loading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar"
        android:theme="@style/ProgressBar" />

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/pb_loading"
        tools:text="Loading text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's my class ProgressDialogFragment:

```
class ProgressDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_dialog_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        tv_message?.text = requireArguments().getString("message", "")
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(message: String) = ProgressDialogFragment().apply {
            arguments = bundleOf(Pair("message", message))
        }
    }

}
```

So, as you can see, now I am creating a new instance each time when I should show the dialog. But is there any way to set the message to the object which already exists? I tried to add the method setMessage which sets message to textview and not to use the new instance in this case, but I caught an exception that textview for the message is not initialized. So, are there any ways to solve my problem?

Comment: it doesn't make sens ... when your fragment would be recreated it would set old message(fx when you rotate screen)

Comment: Are you using livedata? in your companion object you can add a public MutableLiveData<String>() and in onResume you would observe the livedata item and set the text. You can also simply use onResume() to set the text from your bundle.